# Android Kotlin with Dagger2, lateinit var has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I'm a Dagger newb and have a trouble with using it.

What I want to develop is that using RxAndroidBle and to initialize it by Dagger for providing Context.

So I researched how it can be implemented, and I wrote some codes and It seems to be working for me but not working at all.

The followings are my codes.

AppComponent.kt

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AppModule::class,
    BluetoothModule::class,
    AndroidInjectionModule::class])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<BluetoothController> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(app: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

AppModule.kt

```
@Module
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Named("appContext")
    @Singleton
    fun provideContext(application: Application): Context =
            application.applicationContext
}
```

BluetoothModule.kt

```
@Module
class BluetoothModule {

    @Provides
    @Named("rxBleClient")
    @Singleton
    fun provideRxBleClient(@Named("appContext") context: Context):RxBleClient =
            RxBleClient.create(context)
}
```

BluetoothController.kt for injecting by DaggerApplication.

```
class BluetoothController : DaggerApplication() {

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build()
    }
}
```

I've inserted
android:name".BluetoothController"
to AndroidManifest.xml

And this is how I would use it.

```
@field:[Inject Named("rxBleClient")]
lateinit var rxBleClient: RxBleClient
```

But it always occurs an error says: lateinit property context has not been initialized

What things I've missed? Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the below code to make this happen.

1. Create `ActivityBuilderModule` for injecting within the activity. Consider our activity as `MainActivity`

   ```
   @Module
   abstract class ActivityBuilderModule {
        @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules=[MainActivityModule::class])
        abstract fun contributeSplashActivity(): MainActivity
   }
   ```
2. Create your `MainActivityModule`

   ```
   @Module
   class MainActivityModule{
        @Provides()
        fun contributeSplashActivity(mainActivity: MainActivity): 
           MainActivity=mainActivity
    }
   ```
3. Modify your component.

   ```
   @Singleton
   @Component(modules = [
   AppModule::class,
   BluetoothModule::class,
   ActivityBuilderModule::class,
   AndroidInjectionModule::class])
   interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<BluetoothController> {

       @Component.Builder
       interface Builder {

           @BindsInstance
           fun application(app: Application): Builder

           fun build(): AppComponent
       }
   }
   ```
4. Within MainActivity just inject.

   ```
   class MainActivity{
         ...
         @Inject
         lateinit var rxBleClient: RxBleClient
         override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

           AndroidInjection.inject(this)
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         }
   }
   ```

Let us know in case of any issue.

Comment: I've already solved my issue as the way like you suggested :) Thanks! This is the cause I had missed.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

the context object is not initialized before its called

Though i dont know, how chained your initialization are.

Use @Inject to add deppendencies, do something like this

```
    @Module
class BluetoothModule(val context : Context) {

    //@Inject private lateinit var context : Context
    @Provides
    @Named("rxBleClient")
    @Singleton
    fun provideRxBleClient():RxBleClient =
            RxBleClient.create(context)
}
```

let your call be like this

```
val component = AppComponent()
 component.bluetoothModule(appContext)
          .//other calls here
          .build()
```

Comment: I tried that put the injection code for Context separately but it doesn't work.. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: trying adding the context via Bluetooth constructor..... the above code @Awesometic

Comment: It seems the suggested answer doesn't use of the dagger.android features.. AppComponent is already defined with the class extends DaggerApplication class. And I found that it isn't needed to inject between module classes. Is it right? I'm a newb so I searched as much as I can. :) But anyway your answer inspires me in some way and I could get the answer. Thanks.